# How do I know where the tokens are stored?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using Azure ADB2C.
Then, we use ADB2C's custom policy to create a login screen.
After successful login, you will be redirected to SPA.
In other words, the login screen and the SPA are separated.
In such cases, where are the tokens(ex:access token,ID token, refresh token) issued after a successful login stored?
If you are creating your own login screen and using MSAL, you would have the choice of localstorage or sessionstorage.
However, my login screen is created from ADB2C's custom policy and I don't know how to set it up. (Login Screen example:https://XXXXXXX=B2C_1_signin)
Is it set in a custom policy?
Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn’t matter if you’re using custom policy, MSAL still manages the tokens in local or session storage.

Comment: If a custom policy is used, no source code is created using MSAL.
So I thought that MSAL is not used in the login screen by custom policy, is that wrong?
If so, where can I switch between localstorage or sessionstorage on the login screen with custom policies?

Comment: It's not used in a custom policy but it's (can be) still used by your application. Your application uses MSAL to redirect user to specific custom policy. Then MSAL receives response from Azure AD B2C and it's up to the client application to decide where to store tokens.

Comment: Hmmm... I see.
So I am wondering, how does SPA (with MSAL) get the token on the login screen created by the custom policy, as the token is issued after authentication on the login screen?
The login screen and SPA are separated.
Also, the SPA is the redirect destination after a successful login.

Comment: MSAL sdk in SPA redirects user to AAD B2C. User logs in. AAD B2C makes a form post response to SPA with an auth code. MSAL promise handles response and exchahges auth code for tokens in a hidden iframe in your SPA. Tokens get stored in local storage. Take a network trace in chrome browser to see it in action.

Comment: I found an access token embedded in the URL of the redirected SPA, (http://XXXaccess_token=XXXXX)
Do you envision this as being retrieved by MSAL?
Sorry for the rudimentary question.